# The IF statement, IF Function or CASE?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, case

I have some MySQL code that I'm trying to get working, but I'm not entirely sure whether I should be using the IF statement, IF function or CASE operator for what I need. I've been getting confused with what I've been reading online, I can't find anywhere that lays out in simple terms how to use any of them with the correct syntax without getting complicated, so I apologize if this seems like a stupid question.

This code here works:

```
SELECT
  email,
  accountgroup, othercode
FROM
  (SELECT
        email AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        email2 AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        email3 AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts) account
WHERE
  email LIKE '%@%'
  AND accountgroup = '$row3' AND othercode = '$row4';
```

$row3 and $row4 are storing a POST'd user defined value. These values will match the values of a column in the database, however I've also added an -all- and -none- value to this POST'd data, so that the user can choose -all- or -none- accountgroups. My problem is that I'm not sure what to do in the SQL if the user chooses, -all- or -none. I thought an IF statement would do the trick, but my SQL is getting an error, and I'm pretty sure I'm not using the IF statement properly.

```
IF ($row3= '-all-') THEN
SELECT
  email,
  accountgroup, othercode
FROM
  (SELECT
        email AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        email2 AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        email3 AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts) account
WHERE
  email LIKE '%@%'
  AND accountgroup <> '' AND othercode = '$row3';





ELSEIF ($row3 = '-none-') THEN
SELECT
  email,
  accountgroup, othercode
FROM
  (SELECT
        email AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        email2 AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        email3 AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts) account
WHERE
  email LIKE '%@%'
  AND accountgroup = '' AND othercode = '$row4';






ELSE 
SELECT
  email,
  accountgroup, othercode
FROM
  (SELECT
        email AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        email2 AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        email3 AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts) account
WHERE
  email LIKE '%@%'
  AND accountgroup = '$row3' AND othercode = '$row4';

  END IF
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, as well as any sources you may be able to provide that explains the IF statement / functions in a newbie fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It pretty much comes up to you - use what you want to, but in general, CASE is used when there can be multiple condition, like:

```
CASE ( value ) {
  $a = 'a';
  $a = 'b'
  $a = 'c'
  $a = 'd'
  $a = 'e'
  etc.
}
```

That way a case will look nicer; and it will also be more easier to add extra fields.

If you have only 2 ( or more possibilities ) options or multiple *under-options*, then use IF:

```
IF ( $a = a ) {
  IF ( $c = 2 && $d = 4 ) {
    $b = 1
  } ELSE {
    $b = 2
  }
} ELSE {
  $b = 3
}
```

That's in general. But there are a lot of options how and when to use witch one.

*PS: The data shown are just plain examples and not syntax related!*

Answer (score 0):

You could use CASE or IF within certain columns of your query if needed. But in this case you have conditions for the entire SQL query. Just keep this condition handling in PHP, there's no need to do it on the SQL statement.

Comment: Yeah looking at it from a different perspective it makes it so much easier to use PHP. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

According to me use it in php and use the switch case because it is much faster than the if else conditions

More on this is if you really want to have conditions in the sql then please use case.

for better knowledge of case statement in mysql

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html
```

for better knowledge of if statement in mysql

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html
```